# Java 1.4.2 File.listFiles not working properly with CIFS mounts - workaround?

Tags: java, linux, cifs

I'm using Java 1.4.2 and Debian 6.0.3. There's a shared Windows folder in the network, which is correctly mounted to `/mnt/share/` via fstab (e.g. it's fully visible from OS and allows all operations) using CIFS. However, when I try to do this in Java:

```
System.out.println(new File("/mnt/share/").listFiles().length)
```

it would always return `0`, meaning `File[]` returned by `listFiles` is empty. The same problem applies to every subdirectory of `/mnt/share/`. `list` returns empty array as well. Amusingly enough, other `File` functions like "create", "isDirectory" or even "delete" work fine. Directories mounted from USB flash drive (fat32) also work fine.

I tested this on 2 different "shared folders" from different Windows systems; one using domain-based authentication system, another using "simple sharing" - that is, guest access. The situation seems weird, since mounted directories should become a part of a file system, so any program could use it. Or so I thought, at least.

I want to delete a directory in my program, and I currently see no other way of doing it except recursive walking on `listFiles`, so this bug becomes rather annoying. The only "workaround" I could think of is to somehow run an external bash script, but it seems like a terrible solution.

**Edit**: It seems this is 1.4.2-specific bug, everything works fine in Java 6. But I can't migrate, so the problem remains.

Could you suggest some workaround? Preferably without switching to third-party libs instead of native ones, I can't say I like the idea of rewriting the whole project for the sake of single code line.

Comment: Why are you using Java 1.4.2? Maybe you could try with Java 7 and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Because my app will be used on a server with many other apps that are already running for god-knows-how-long, and higher-ups at my company are afraid to migrate because of potential backward compatibility problems. It wouldn't hurt to try it with newer version, though; I guess it's time to install Debian at home. Still, would appreciate any suggestions while I'm on it.

Comment: You can use multiple versions of java on the same machine.

Comment: I know that much (I actually DO have 1.6.0 installed together with 1.4.2), it's just that I didn't have an idea of testing it with another version, but I'm away from work now, and have 3 days off ahead. Probably wasn't the best idea to ask that question today, but whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, two and half years later after giving up I encounter the same problem, again stuck with 1.4.2 because I need to embed the code into obsolete Oracle Forms 10g version.

If someone, by chance, stumbles onto this problem and decides to solve it properly, not hack his way through, it most probably has to do with (highly) unusual inode mapping that CIFS does upon mounting the remote filesystem, causing more obscure bugs some of which can be found on serverfault. One of the side-effects of such mapping is that all directories have zero hard-link count. Another one is that all directories have "size" of exactly 0, instead of usual "sector size or more", which can be checked even with `ls`.

I can't be sure without examining the (proprietary) source code, but I can guess that Java prior to 1.5 used some shortcut like checking link count internally instead of actually calling readdir() with C, which works equally well for any mounted FS.

Anyway, the second side-effect can be used to create a simple wrapper around File which won't rely on system calls unless it suspects a directory is mounted using CIFS. Other versions of `list` and `listFiles` functions in `java.io.File`, even ones using filters, rely on `list()` internally, so it's OK to override only it.

I didn't care about `listFiles` returning `File[]` not `FileEx[]` so I didn't bother to override it, but is should be simple enough. Obviously, that code can work only in Unix-like systems having `ls` command handy.

```
package FSTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileEx extends File
{
    public FileEx(String path)
    {
        super(path);
    }

    public FileEx(File f)
    {
        super(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public String[] list()
    {
        if (this.canRead() && this.isDirectory())
            {
            /*
             * Checking the length of dir is not the most reliable way to distinguish CIFS mounts.
             * However, zero directory length generally indicates something unusual,
             * so calling ls on it wouldn't hurt. Ordinary directories don't suffer any overhead this way.
             * If this "zero-size" behavior is ever changed by CIFS but list() still won't work,
             * it will be safer to call super.list() first and call this.listUsingExec if returned array has 0 elements.
             * Though it might have serious performance implications, of course.
             */
            if (this.length() > 0)
                return super.list();
            else
                return this.listUsingExec();
           }
        else
            return null;
    }

    private String[] listUsingExec()
    {
        Process p;
        String command = "/bin/ls -1a " + this.getAbsolutePath();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        try
            {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
                {
                if (!line.equalsIgnoreCase(".") && !line.equalsIgnoreCase(".."))
                    list.add(line);
               }
            String[] ret = new String[list.size()];
            list.toArray(ret);
            return ret;
           }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
            return null;
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Java 1.2` there is method `File.getCanonicalFile()`. In your case with mounted directory you should use exactly this one in such style:

`new File("/mnt/share/").getCanonicalFile().listFiles()`

Comment: Alas, no. It was among the first things I tried, and that yielded the same result.